# Is there a way to dynamically upload catalog items from my database to PayPal Here using the API?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm looking to see if it's possible to add catalog items that are always changing with code rather than manually entering them one by one.  I want to do this to make use of the barcode scanning feature on the PayPal Here POS app in a store that never sells the same item twice.

Here is the entry page I'm looking to automate with the PayPal API:
[image of PayPal interface (was too new to stackoverflow to embed it)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGtmJ.png)

I haven't found a hint of this in the API docs or on the web.  Does anyone know if it's possible?